# Where must finisher files (for powermail finisher) be located?

Tags: typo3, powermail

I am currently trying to add a finisher to my powerplay form.

The target is to delete all elements in a specific folder after the form is submited.

I currently use :
[this tutorial](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/ForDevelopers/AddFinisherClasses/Index.html)

I first put this into my `setup.txt`

```
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup {
finishers {
    1 {
        class = Vendor\Ext\Finisher\DoSomethingFinisher
    }
}
```

}

at this location: `ftp://ftpIP/typo3cms/pagename/typo3conf/ext/powermail/Configuration/TypoScript/Main/setup.txt`

Now i should create a PHP-File:

> Add a php-file DoSomethingFinisher.php and extend your class with the AbstractFinisher from powermail:

But where shuld I place that PHP File? In the same place as the `setup.txt`?

Hope someone can help. Thank you very much.

Thomas

Answer (score 2):

That question is related to TYPO3 autoloading and not to powermail. If you want to add PHP-Files to your TYPO3, you should use an extension.
There are some manuals how to get the autoloading to work with your PHP-Files (see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Autoloading/Index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't modify the files in the folder `powermail`, otherwise you will be in trouble when you want to update the extension. Instead, create a new extension with [extension_builder](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/extension_builder/) or take [powermailextended](https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermailextended) and modify that extension.

Assuming you use powermailextended:

If you call the Finisher `In2code\Powermailextended\Finisher\MyFinisher`, then it needs to go in `EXT:powermailextend\Classes\Finisher\MyFinisher` - this is how Typo3 autoloads the PHP files.